# I need to move a set of files after getting the list from a json array, to location using Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a json file like below as an input

```
{
  "files": [
    "file1.xml",
    "file2.xml",
    "file4.xml"
  ]
}
```

I need to move the set of files obtained from json array above, to location using Nifi

Comment: Start from SplitJson

Answer (score 0):

SplitJson --> ExtractText --> FetchFile

for easier understanding example template

https://pastefs.com/pid/292381